# Multiple asynchronous tracking on Google Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

My goal was to setup 2 trackings on each website : one specific to the website, and a second to aggregate the data of websites which belong to a network.

```
here is the code i implemented :

// UA-XXXXXXXX-1 = Global tracking
// UA-XXXXXXXX-2 = Specific tracking

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Type", "Value_Type", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
var _gaq2 = _gaq2 || [];
_gaq2.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2']);
_gaq2.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

This code is not working : specific tracking is not working. Any idea why ?
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should rather look like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Type", "Value_Type", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

_gaq.push(['SPECIFIC._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2']);
_gaq.push(['SPECIFIC._trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Its still showing as "code not installed" in GA.
Any other idea why just the "specific" is not coming up ?
Thanks !

Comment: At this point it would be helpful if we could look at the website in question - I'm running this exact code on several sites without problems, so I guess it's okay.

Comment: You're right,tracking is now working, but google analytics status in admin keeps saying 'tracking not installed'. I guess it's because the code installed is not the same as code proposed by google (because of this double variables)